# How can i remove this string split problem in java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like this in my Java Program

```
String str = ("System.out.print(Numerator?)int");
```

And i hava a delimiter to split the element

```
 private static final String DELIMITER = "\"(?:\\\\\"|[^\"])*?\"|[\\s.,;:+*/|!=><@?#%&(){}\\-\\^\\[\\]\\&&]+|int";
```

and print out

```
for (String retval: str.split(DELIMITER)){
            System.out.println(retval);
}
```

but the output is

```
System
out
pr

Numerator
```

i want the output is

```
System 
out 
print
Numerator
```

How to fix it by only split the "int"  not pr"int".

Comment: I think it would suffice to add the word boundary `\b` to the "int" in your delimiter, so that it doesn't match the pattern "int" inside of a word. -> `"...\\bint\\b";`

Comment: @maloomeister yes i fix the problem by using your method . thank you

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

See context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = ("System.out.print(Numerator?)int");
    List<String> elements = Pattern.compile("\\W|\\bint\\b").splitAsStream(input).collect(Collectors.toList());
    elements.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
System
out
print
Numerator
```